# TYPO3 v12.4 How do I change the entryLevel in HMENU if the currenty level has no items?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

can someone explain to me, why this TypoScript doesn't work in version 12.4 anymore. I am updating from 7.6 and thought treeLevel -> tree.level was the only change in this regard.

here is my code:

```
lib._submenu = HMENU
lib._submenu {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {      
        expAll = 1
        NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
        IFSUB = 1
        IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="hasSub">|</li>
        ACT < .NO
        ACT = 1
        ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
        ACT.ATagParams = class="active"    
        ACTIFSUB = 1
        ACTIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="hasSub active">|</li>
        ACTIFSUB.ATagParams = class="active" 
        SPC = 1
        SPC.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="trenner">|</li>
        SPC.doNotShowLink = 0 
    }
    stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject = HMENU
    stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject {
        1 = TMENU
        1 {      
            expAll = 1
            NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
            IFSUB = 1
            IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="hasSub">|</li>
            ACT < .NO
            ACT = 1
            ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
            ACT.ATagParams = class="active"    
            ACTIFSUB = 1
            ACTIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="hasSub active">|</li>
            ACTIFSUB.ATagParams = class="active" 
            SPC = 1
            SPC.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="trenner">|</li>
            SPC.doNotShowLink = 0 
        }
    }
}

[tree.level == 1]
lib._submenu {
    entryLevel = 1
}
[END]

[tree.level == 2]
lib._submenu {
    entryLevel = 2
    stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject = HMENU
    stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject {
        entryLevel = 1
    }
}
[END]

[tree.level == 3]
lib._submenu {
    entryLevel = 3
    stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject = HMENU
    stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject {
        entryLevel = 2
    }
}
[END]

[tree.level == 4]
lib._submenu {
    entryLevel = 4
    stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject = HMENU
    stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject {
        entryLevel = 3
    }
}
[END]
```

I have been searching for a solution the past week, but it seems noone ever did a menu like that. It should show the pages of the current level, but when there are none it should display the items of the previous level.

Answer (score 1):

Entry level is not about the level the menu actually starts with, but about the level at which that menu becomes visible. So even with former versions of TYPO3 CMS the code should not work as expected.

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html#entrylevel

What you actually want seems to be something like this:

```
10 = HMENU
10 {
  special = directory
  special.value.data = leveluid: -1
  stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject = HMENU
  stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject {
    special = directory
    special.value.data = leveluid: -2
  }
}
```

The good thing about this approach is, that you don not need any conditions and therefore you reduce the amount of cached variants which is good for performance.

Comment: well, actually it worked just fine in typo3 7.6.32 . trying your code doesn't create any output for the menu. what i am trying to achive is that the submenu shows the subpages of the current page and if there are no more subpages it should show the pages of the level before

Comment: That's exactly what the code above does and it did it even before 7.6.32 ;-)

The so called "level fields" can hold positive values or negative values. Negative values go back through the rootline and start with the current page. So -1 IS the current page, -2 the parent page and so on.

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/12.4/en-us/Functions/Data.html#leveltitle-leveluid-levelmedia

If this does not work too, there might be something broken within your rootline, that breaks both approaches.

Comment: thank you. still, your code works if there are subpages. but when there are none, it doesn't. by my logical understanding it should, so it seems something with the ifEmpty isn't working in general in this installation. sadly i have absolutely no clue where to check. it is a fresh 12.4.9 installation

Comment: Most likely there are some wraps in the original HMENU code, that might create something else than the menu structure itself but still more than really empty content.

So you should make sure to move all the wraps either into the TMENU part or to a surrounding COA to keep the actual HMENU empty, if there are no subpages.